# What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a Bernoulli Random Variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a Bernoulli Random Variable? Does this depend on the context and how we define the sample space?

I know that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the indicator function on event $A$ is always by $\{\phi, A, A^{c}, \mathbb{R}\}$, but was wondering if there is also a general result for Bernoulli.

Context: A question in actuarial science asked for the mean of $X = BY$, where $B\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $Y$ is some real-valued variable with a given distribution. To calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$, we needed to use the tower property to deduce $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]=p\mathbb{E}[Y].$$
However, the tower property can only be applied if the $\sigma$-algebra that $Y$ is defined on contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B$. I guess since this is not a math subject these technical details can be glossed over, but I am still curious as to whether a general result exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"However, the tower property can only be applied if the $\sigma$-algebra that $Y$ is defined on contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B$". This is not true in your example (assuming that $B$ and $Y$ are independent) where a special case of the tower property (the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)) is applied to $\mathcal{G}_2=\sigma(B)$ and $\mathcal{G}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ (as defined in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case)).

---

Also $\sigma(B)$ is of the form $\{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}$ with $A=B^{-1}(\{0\})$, which depends on the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$.

Answer (score 1):

If $( \Omega, \Sigma, P)$ is a probability space and if $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is measurable with respect to the Borel $ - \sigma -$ algebra $ \mathcal{B}( \mathbb R)$, then

$$\sigma(X):=\{ X^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal{B}( \mathbb R)\}$$

is called the $ - \sigma -$ algebra generated by $X.$